# SSH tunnel on Google Compute Engine VM instance to a different host and port

Tags: google-compute-engine, ssh-tunnel

I want to configure a SSH tunnel on a Google Compute Engine VM instance (Debian). Requests to port 80 on the VM should be directed to port 8888 on the different host. (SSH uses port 2222 on the other host.)

I enter this command in the VM:

```
$ sudo ssh root@mydyndnsdomain -L 80:mydyndnsdomain:8888 -p 2222 -N -4 -f
```

(when I run the same command on my local Linux server, the SSH tunnel works)

... and then I can verify that the VM is listening to port 80 with `fuser`:

```
$ sudo fuser 80/tcp
80/tcp:               6303
```

or with `netstat`:

```
$ netstat -a | grep "LISTEN"
tcp        0      0 localhost:http          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     3120     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11464    /var/run/apache2/cgisock.4602
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4827     /var/run/acpid.socket
```

But when I browse to the IP adress of the VM, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome.

(Port 80 is opened in my Google Compute Engine network. I verified this by running Apache2 server on port 80 and browsing to the IP address of the VM. It worked.)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can u clarify what is your `local Linux server`, `VM`, `different server` and `mydyndnsdomain`? Its confusing as what you are referring where.

Comment: `local linux server` is actually Cygwin running on my Windows 7 laptop. `VM` is the Google Compute Engine VM instance. `mydyndnsdomain` is a dynamic DNS domain that maps to the non-static IP address of my NAS server.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess connecting to your external IP from your NAS doesn't work due to your home router.
What about `sudo ssh root@mydyndnsdomain -L 80:127.0.0.1:8888 -p 2222 -N -4 -f`?